# Update records from CVS file or drop all table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

well this is the first time in this forum so I'II be clear about my question and thanks in advance

I'll create a software in C#, this app takes a CSV file (about 73,000 lines). This files comes from another system, also the CSV file can change, what's that means? the CSV file can change in one line ( the data ) or can have more new lines or can have less lines, the CSV change every hour or half hour it depends!!!

I add those lines from the CSV file to a table in SQL,The first time is easy.. I just ADDNEW for each line in CSV file. But, the second time I cannot delete all table to import it again from the beginning because of these extra fields, or in other case if a line in the CSV change, i can't drop all the data from the table.

so I need a method that can verify each record inside my SQL Table and CSV file automatically? Or I need to treat the records one by one? If i compare every change it would be correct to use a cursor fot that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's not a simple answer to this; it's a process.

First, what version of SQL Server are you using?  If you're using SQL Server 2008, you have access to the MERGE T-SQL command, which can allow you to fashion an "upsert" command (UPDATE or INSERT depending on the presence of data).  If you're using something older, the coding gets a little more complex, but not impossible.

Second, when you load your data, always load into a staging table first.  This allows you to do set-based comparisons, and "upsert" as necessary.  In 99.999% of the cases, you should be able to do this without a cursor, and have it perform better.

Stu

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using SSIS to directly load the data and don't want to use a staging table for some reason, and you have some kind of key you can use to order the rows, you can use the [TableDifference custom component](http://sqlbi.eu/Projects/TableDifference/tabid/74/Default.aspx).  Basically, you read both the "old" table and the "new" table into two separate flows, sort them in the same order and pass them through the TableDifference.  This generates 3 potential outputs - INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs.  INSERTs can usually be handled with a regular insert task, but UPDATEs and DELETEs can either use individual command invocations or can stream to staging tables to batch the UPDATE or DELETE operation.

Answer (score 0):

now i solved my problem using table diff ssi, now I'm working with that, thanks to all and c ya later